# How do I show exactly the same color in UIToolbar and NavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to add a UIToolbar that shows the user karma in a NavigationBar. The problem I have is that the colors are not exactly equals, as you can see at the photo.

[image]

So, any idea How could I resolve this? Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];
UIToolbar *tools = [[UIToolbar alloc]
                    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 80.0f, 45.00f)];

UILabel *karma = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0f, 0.0f, 40.0f, 44.00f)];
karma.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"karma"];
karma.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:(14.0)];
karma.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(255.0) green:(255.0) blue:(255.0) alpha:1];
karma.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(64/255.0) green:(64/255.0) blue:(64/255.0) alpha:0];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_people.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 7.5f, 30.0f, 30.00f);
// Add Pin button.

[tools setBarStyle: UIBarStyleDefault];
[tools addSubview:karma];
[tools addSubview:imageView];

// Add toolbar to nav bar.
UIBarButtonItem *karmaNav = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = karmaNav;
...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not embed your karma label and image inside of a UIView instead of a UIToolbar. Then, you'd be able to set the background color of that UIView to clearColor.

Something like this:

```
UIView *tools = [[UIView alloc]
                    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 80.0f, 45.00f)];
tools.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UILabel *karma = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0f, 0.0f, 40.0f, 44.00f)];
karma.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"karma"];
karma.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:(14.0)];
karma.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(255.0) green:(255.0) blue:(255.0) alpha:1];
karma.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(64/255.0) green:(64/255.0) blue:(64/255.0) alpha:0];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_people.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 7.5f, 30.0f, 30.00f);

[tools addSubview:karma];
[tools addSubview:imageView];

UIBarButtonItem *karmaNav = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = karmaNav;
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a solution ;) But why it does not work in UIToolbar?

Comment: UIToolbar's aren't exactly meant for what you're wanting. I guess technically you could use a UIToolbar in this case, but a UIView is exactly what you'd want for this situation. You can do some research on UIToolbar [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and UIView [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).